# jQuery ~ copy content from div to div using .next('div')

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I am attempting to produce a table, that with each row selected, a dialog will appear with additional data specific to the row selected.

I am trying this one method which uses a 'holder' div from which content is moved to, then `.dialog()` is executed at.

```
<table border="1">
   <tr>
     <td><b>Customer</b></td>
     <td><b>Phone umber</b></td>
     <td><b>Time</b></td>
   </tr>
   <tr class="ref">
     <td>111111</td>
     <td>111111</td>
     <td>111111</td>
     <td><div style="display: none;">Hello, World!</div></td>                  
   </tr>
   <tr class="ref">
     <td>222222</td>
     <td>222222</td>
     <td>222222</td>
     <td><div style="display: none;">Hello, Again!</div></td>
  </tr>
</table> 

<div id="holder" class="hold">test...</div>
```

```
 $('.ref').on('click', function (){
       $('#holder').html($(this).next('div').html());

       $('#holder').dialog();
  });
```

This Does Not Work. with the current code, the holder div's initial content of 'test...' is just opened in the dialog.

i have also tried using `.innerHTML` when selecting the element, however this only returns '`undefined`'

I used `console.log($(this).next('div').html())`, which returns '`undefined`'

EDIT:
as pointed out, incorrect HTML with `<div>` now encapsulated with `<td>`

Comment: Invalid Html.! `tr` cannot have `Div` as its direct child.

Comment: you have an invalid html -> `tr` can't have `div` as a child.. change it to `<td>222222<div style="display: none;">Hello, Again!</div></td>` then `$('#holder').html($(this).children('div').html());`

Comment: i had previously tried using the div inside its own <td> with no sucsess

Comment: Then change it to a `span`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this : use `.find()` instead of `.next()`

`.next()` will find next sibling i.e. next `tr`, while `.find()` will look for its descendent.

```
$('.ref').on('click', function (){
       $('#holder').html($(this).find('div').html());

       $('#holder').dialog();
  });
```

Also `tr` can't have `div` as direct child so wrap it in `td` like below :

```
<tr class="ref">
     <td>222222</td>
     <td>222222</td>
     <td>222222</td>
     <td><div style="display: none;">Hello, Again!</div></td>
  </tr>
```

Above jquery will work after wraping `div` in `td` also

Comment: thanks very much, i will accept as answer once the timeout has finished